# Trying to pass the path of the clicked file to loadExcelData...Anyone have any ideas

Tags: python, qtreeview

Here is the issue. Disregarding my inital question for now regarding passing the path, I just filled in the path for function loadExcelData 'C:\Query1.xlsx' directly. The issue is I can only get Query1.xlsx to load into QtableWidget using the first method which involves calling the function directly. When I try event/callback I get the following error

CALL DEF DIRECTLY-works

```
 class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
```

"   "

"   "

```
    self.treeView.clicked.connect(
        lambda _, xl_path=excel_file_path, sheet_name=worksheet_name: 
       self.loadExcelData(xl_path, sheet_name))
```

---

EVENT/CALLBACK-this doesn't work

I get "Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)"

```
  class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

  "   "

  "   "
     self.treeView.clicked.connect(self.test)

     def test(self, signal):
         loadExcelData(self, file_path)



   def loadExcelData(self, xl_path, worksheet_name):
         df = pd.read_excel('C:\Query1.xlsx')

         "   "

    Do I need a pyqt slot?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is just to create an event/callback function that's connected to your treeView's "clicked" signal/trigger and call your "loadExcelData" and any other logic from the connected function:

```
self.treeView.clicked.connect(this.viewClicked)

def viewClicked(self):
   self.loadExcelData(self.model.filepath, sheet_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Within def test I forgot self when calling loadExcelDate

so loadExcelData -> self.loadExcelData